# Passing Array of Objects to Controller using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, arraylist

I'm a little new to Spring MVC and I'm having trouble with one of my controller methods where I am passing two parameters: one object and the other an array of objects. I'm using an Ajax call to POST the data to the API Controller, but I get the following error returned every time for the array of objects:

> Failed to instantiate [[Lcom.name.models.UserAccessListMembers;]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:

Here is the controller method:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/user/save/accesslist", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveAccessList(UserAccessLists list, UserAccessListMembers[] members){

    <code here>
}
```

Here is the javascript:

```
var newEntries = [];
        var newEntry = {"id" : null, "listId" : 1, "wwid" : "abc123" };
        newEntries.push(newEntry);
        var theList = {"id": 1, "userId" : null, "name": "new list" };
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: window.contextPath + '/api/user/save/accesslist',
            data: {list : theList, members : newEntries },
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function () {
                  <do stuff>
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("xhr: ", xhr);
            }
        });
```

And finally here is the class **UserAccessListMembers**:

```
public class UserAccessListMembers implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer id;
private Integer listId;
private String wwid;
private String personName;

public UserAccessListMembers() {
}

public UserAccessListMembers(Integer id, Integer listId, String wwid) {
    this.id = id;
    this.listId = listId;
    this.wwid = wwid;
}
   < getters and setters below here >
}
```

You can see I have two constructors in the UserAccessListMembers class, a default constructor and one that includes all the necessary properties. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong or if I am missing a piece as I come from a .NET MVC background.

Can anyone help me figure out how to get Spring MVC to map and instantiate the class correctly? What are some of the best practices in java here for sending objects to an MVC Controller?

Comment: Don't we need `@RequestParam` or `@RequestBody` for these parameters?

Comment: I tried RequestParam with no luck and just tried RequestBody it throws an error saying that the "Content Type is not supported - urlformencoded..."

Comment: Ah, maybe because you have two json parameters, try to wrap them in a single class and use request body annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using maven add something like the following to you pom so Jackson is in the classpath:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

As long as you pass the correct json to the controller it will de-serialize it.

To test it you can use the following:

```
public class JacksonTest {
    @Test
    public void test1() throws IOException {
        String test = "[{\"id\" : null, \"listId\" : 1, \"wwid\" : \"abc123\"}]";
        UserAccessListMembers[] userAccessListMemberses = new ObjectMapper().readValue(test, UserAccessListMembers[].class);
        for (UserAccessListMembers members : userAccessListMemberses) {
            System.out.println(members);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In Java List is an interface and cannot be instantiated. So I wouldn't be able to use it on the Controller method. I do have a No-Arg constructor. Lastly, is Jackson embedded in Spring MVC? Because for anything JSON we are using Googel Gson package.

Comment: Sorry bad answer I have updated, I think you're missing Jackson in your classpath.

Comment: I have added Jackson in the class path but it is still not working.

Comment: I see that my ajax request is using application/www-form-urlencoded content type since the button click is a submit button

Comment: @Encryption jackson may need to be configured as a converter. Also, I still think you'll need to wrap the two parameters in a single class and change the content type to application/json.

Comment: @grape_mao I've changed the content type to application/json now but still no luck. It will make it to the controller but everything in the object is NULL. So it is like it didn't read the object and serialize it properly

Comment: @Encryption Spring should do it automatically with jackson present in class path...I don't know exactly your probem. Maybe test it with postman first.

Comment: I finally got it working. Jackson is doing the trick and I had to add "@RequestBody" in the method args.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate class named `UserAccessListMembersArray` and in that class  create a field `List<UserAccessListMembers> members;` and use the new class as argument of your controller method. Goodluck.